# Use hyphen(-) instead of slash(/) or underscore( _ ) in Routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm Using Codeigniter 3.x , Using **routes.php** I want to create dynamic routes,  for example I have a class name `Class1`.

I want output url

> **mysite.com/Class1-Student-Search**

But using hyphen(-) is not working

If I put a slash(/), it works,

```
$route['(:any)/Student-Search']  = "search";
```

it returns

> **mysite.com/Class1/Student-Search**

and using underscore (_) also work.

```
$route['(:any)_Student-Search']  = "search";
```

returns

> **mysite.com/Class1_Student-Search**

But I want to use hyphen(-), if I put it, it will go to 404 error page, I used these four solutions but not work for me.

```
$route['(:any)-Student-Search']  = "search";
$route['([a-zA-Z]+)-Student-Search']  = "search";
$route['([a-zA-Z-0-9]+)-Student-Search']  = "search";
$route['(.*)-Student-Search']  = "search";
```

And if i hardcode the value in route

```
$route['Class1-Student-Search']  = "search";
```

Then it also working

Comment: Have you set `$route['translate_uri_dashes'];` to `TRUE` ??

Comment: yes i set it @Saty

Comment: It's a regular expressions. Try to escape them: `\\-Student\\-Search`

Comment: not working @vp_arth

Comment: Check this [LINK](http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-routes-tutorial) point Dash based URLs

Comment: Also [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-instead-of-_-in-CodeIgniter-3-0)

Comment: Maybe their docs would help http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=route

Comment: go to config.php file and check the permitted_uri_chars and match it with this
`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z A-Z 0-9~%.:_\-=';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to create a dynamic routes which is not possible in **codeigniter** if you see the following flow chart of codeigniter you understand what i mean.

[image]

also you can see this chart in codeigniter official [website](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html)

when you try to redirect or call some url it's work like this

[image]

Every request first goes to route there for you can't make it dynamic

Comment: Codeigniter official website is now http://www.codeigniter.com and you now can find both docs here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs Ellislab does not deal with CI any more. But for some reason they still have links.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution, it is working for me, do like this.

```
$route['(:any)-Student-Search']  = "search";
```

then in your link button, hopefully in your view, href the link like this.

```
href="/<?php echo $row->classname; ?>-Student-Search"
```

the point is that not only you have to make your routes, also suffix it in your href link also the same way.

Comment: What is that (:any) mean in your answer it's mean your call first goes to routs then routs check to go any of callas. that guy want to call first class then route which is not possible in codeigniter

Comment: (:any) means the actual id he is passing, the route will check for the id number and then go to the class.
He can pass the id to the route, then query the data, and load the relevant details of it.

Comment: read the Question care fully he want's to send the request to some class where he want's defined some function and then hit the routs which is not possible.